# Problema com os scripts bundle

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bundle

Quando publico minha aplicação asp.net mvc o script bundle gera um problema ref. scripts.

Como no ambiente de debug não utilizo os bundles o problema não acontece.

### Erro:

> "~common/scripts": Duplicate data property in object literal not allowed in strict mode.

### Global.asa branca:

```
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());

        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = !HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled;
```

### Bundle Register:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/base/scripts").Include("~/Scripts/Site.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/modernizr").Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.7.2.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/metro/scripts").Include("~/Scripts/Metro/metro.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/jquery/scripts").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js", "~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js", "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js", "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js", "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js", "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/common/scripts").Include("~/Scripts/Common/jquery.ui.dialogr.js", "~/Scripts/Common/jquery.select2.js", "~/Scripts/Common/jquery.maskedinput.js", "~/Scripts/Common/jquery.number.js", "~/Scripts/Common/jquery.float-thead.js", "~/Scripts/Common/jquery.tablesorter.js"));
```

Comment: Você pode adicionar o resto do seu global.asax por favor?

Comment: Alterei, está tudo ai!

Comment: Seus scripts estão estendendo a mesma propriedade duas vezes (ou mais), por isso o aviso. O inspector do seu browser dá a dica de qual script é?

Comment: No script select2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema criando os `virtuais path` dos `bundles` de acordo com as `pastas físicas`.

### Por exemplo:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/content/css/metro").Include("~/Content/Css/metro-bootstrap.css", "~/Content/Css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css", "~/Content/Css/iconFont.css"));
```

> ~/content/css - indica que os arquivos estão nessa pasta e quando carregar uma imagem em um css incluido nesse bundle, por exemplo, ele vai usar essa pasta como path inicial. No  meu caso era o javascript que fazia o load de um recurso e não conseguia!

Infelizmente o `Asp.NET MVC` juntamente com seu `System.Web.Optimization` usa o virtual path como se fosse um path real que acaba atrapalhando o load de recursos internos dos css ou javascripts.

Temos duas opções nesse caso:

- Criar uma padronização dos arquivos css, scripts, fontes e imagens no projeto, perdendo a maior vantagem do Nuget e a cada atualização ter que organizar os arquivos e os path dos recursos externos manualmente.
- Criar diversos bundles para cada plugin que fizer o uso de recursos externos como imagens e fontes, aumentando a quantidade de requisições.

Boa Asp.NET MVC xD!